# Changing referenced SQL column in all Tableau Server reports

Tags: sql, xml, tableau-api

We have an extremely popular column in a database (let's call it "column_a").
That column is being changed to "column_b"
We need to change every report that points to "column_a" to "column_b"
What's the best way?

In the past at a previous company I believe that someone on my team was able to export the entire tableau server of reports into XML, search and replace, and then reimport.  I can't find anything online related to that.

Does anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option at the database level which might work well for you.  You can create one or more *views* on top of the table where `column_a` has been renamed to `column_b`.  In the select for the view, simply alias the now `column_b` back to `column_a`.  For example, in MySQL you could do:

```
CREATE VIEW someView AS
SELECT column_b AS column_a, col2, col3, ...
FROM yourTable
```

Now anything upstream, e.g. Tableau, could continue referring to `column_a` as it was previously, and nothing needs to change there.  Note that you can use the view as you would an actual table.  So you might need to point the reporting tools from the old table to a new view, but that might be the only change needed.

Comment: Thank you much. Went down his approach. Unfortunately can’t do Bc environment is a system environment and policy doesn’t allow for views. I know I know I know but I inherited this architecture. :$